# Numbered back references for groups with subgroups

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I have the word 'fan(s)' I want to replace with the word fanatic(s) when preceeded by a pronoun verb combo seen below.

```
gsub(
    "(((s?he( i|')s)|((you|they|we)( a|')re)|(I( a|')m)).{1,20})(\\b[Ff]an)(s?\\b)", 
    '\\1\\2atic\\3', 
    'He\'s the bigest fan I know.', 
    perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE
)

## [1] "He's the bigest He'saticHe's I know."
```

I know the numbered back references are refering to the inner parenthesis of the first group.  Is there a way to have them refer to just the outter three parenthesis where the three groups are: `(stuff before fan)(fan)(s\\b)` in pseudocode.

I know my regex can replace wll the groups si I know it's valid.  It's just the backreference portion.

```
gsub(
    "(((s?he( i|')s)|((you|they|we)( a|')re)|(I( a|')m)).{1,20})(\\b[Ff]an)(s?\\b)", 
    '', 
    'He\'s the bigest fan I know.', 
    perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE
)

## [1] " I know."
```

Desired output:

```
## [1] "He's the bigest fanatic I know."
```

### Examples of matches

```
inputs <- c(
    "He's the bigest fan I know.",
    "I am a huge fan of his.",
    "I know she has lots of fans in his club",
    "I was cold and turned on the fan",
    "An air conditioner is better than 2 fans at cooling."
)


outputs <- c(
    "He's the bigest fanatic I know.",
    "I am a huge fanatic of his.",
    "I know she has lots of fanatics in his club",
    "I was cold and turned on the fan",
    "An air conditioner is better than 2 fans at cooling."
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you have trouble with the excessive amount of capturing groups. Turn those you are not interested in into [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) ones, or remove those that are plain redundant:

```
((?:s?he(?: i|')s|(?:you|they|we)(?: a|')re|I(?: a|')m).{1,20})\b(Fan)(s?)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3qlG4/1)

Note that `[Ff]` can be turned into `F` or `f` since you are uisng `ignore.case=TRUE` argument.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/fbYhl1):

```
gsub(
    "((?:s?he(?: i|')s|(?:you|they|we)(?: a|')re|I(?: a|')m).{1,20})\\b(fan)(s?)\\b", 
    '\\1\\2atic\\3', 
    inputs, 
    perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE
)
```

Output:

```
[1] "He's the bigest fanatic I know."                     
[2] "I am a huge fanatic of his."                         
[3] "I know she has lots of fans in his club"             
[4] "I was cold and turned on the fan"                    
[5] "An air conditioner is better than 2 fans at cooling."
```

Comment: Thanks...learned a new pretty easy thing about regex...much appreciated.